# Buttons all open the same activity from an Android fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Currently I have a `fragment_one.xml` which has 5 `CardViews` on it and and each card has a Button on it that is meant to go to separate XML pages (Lesson_One,Lesson_Two etc...) but with the code I have in  `OneFragment.java`, both buttons are opening `Lesson_Two`

How I can I fix this? Here is my code

> FragmentOne.java

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{
   Intent intent;  

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LessonOne.class);
    final Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LessonTwo.class);
    final Button button2 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return root;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning `intent` twice, effectively overwriting the first intent with the second.

So no matter which click event is triggered `LessonTwo.class` is the activity that is started.

A simple fix would be to create the intents inside the click handlers like

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    final Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LessonOne.class));
        }
    });

    final Button button2 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LessonTwo.class););
        }
    });

    return root;
  }

}
```

This makes it explicit which click handler starts what activity

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer - implement the click listener on the class itself.

This cleans up the `onCreateView` method. You also don't need to "capture" the buttons to set their listeners.

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        root.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
        root.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Class clz = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                clz = LessonOne.class;
            case R.id.button2;
                clz = LessonTwo.class;
        }

        if (clz != null) startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), clz));

    }

}
```